# Plotly Funnel Chart not changing xaxis ticks in billions to B

Tags: python, plotly, graphing, exponent

I was wondering if it were possible to have the plotly funnel chart represent numbers in the billions as two decimals with B at the end, not G. Everything I have tried has led to it being shown as G. Here is my code:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go

stages = ['Kazakhstan', 'Uzbekistan', 'Azerbaijan', 'Armenia', 'Georgia']

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'China',
    y = stages,
    x = [7823406346.0, 1762654355.0, 752162634.0, 227629540.0, 193681983.0],
    textposition = "auto",
#     textinfo = "value+percent previous"
 constraintext='outside',
    textfont=dict(
        family="sans serif",
        size=14,
        color="navy"
    )

   )
)

fig.update_layout(xaxis = dict(exponentformat = 'B', hoverformat = '$.2s'))
fig.show()
```

Even though I have changed the exponentformat to B, and the hoverformat to include $ (I have tried every combination with no luck), this has not changed. I have even tried tickformater to the various options ($.2s, etc), and this also has had no impact. Thank you for any help in finding out if it is possible to change the G to B in the xaxis ticks.